# Automatically import content to wordpress from a json file

Tags: json, automation

I have a scrape that generates content in JSON format and can be obtained by GET to a specific URL, the URL from which to extract information is this: https://api.webscraper.io/api/v1/scraping-job/4851593/json?api_token=aLXQWr2IbQCefgiLc1PfIjfx7GqvsBd3APVbU1pHchszzzFIFa6HFKsNmpft

I would like to be able to connect this with my WP so that the content is published automatically.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to add a new post programmatically. For Example,

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $json->title ),
  'post_content'  => $json->body,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => $json->categories
);
 
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Your link has expired so I could not see the structure of JSON data. But the answer would be the same. Set up a [cron job](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) or use their webhook (if they have any) to call a page where you have set up this `wp_insert_post()`for automatic posting.

Comment: I updated the JSON link: https://api.webscraper.io/api/v1/scraping-job/4851593/json?api_token=aLXQWr2IbQCefgiLc1PfIjfx7GqvsBd3APVbU1pHchszzzFIFa6HFKsNmpft

Comment: Use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), set up a [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop for array and use `$json['titulo_post']` for title and `$json['contenido_post']` for contents on the snippet above. Also, we can only help you to solve problem. You still have to do your own homework. I would recommend you to hire some professional if you are not fimilier with Wordpress Codex and PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand the logic, first I decode the JSON and store it in an array to use it later use it in wp_insert_post (), I will post the code once I have it solved in case it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

write a custom simple script that retrieves the json data and creates wp posts using the wp REST API and replace the `$json_url` variable with the URL of your JSON endpoint

we added a `post_exists()` function to check if a post with the same title already exists in the wp database

```
// URL of the JSON endpoint
$json_url = 'https://api.webscraper.io/api/v1/scraping-job/4851593/json?api_token=aLXQWr2IbQCefgiLc1PfIjfx7GqvsBd3APVbU1pHchszzzFIFa6HFKsNmpft';

// Retrieve JSON data
$response = file_get_contents($json_url);

// Check if data was successfully retrieved
if ($response === false) {
    die('Failed to fetch JSON data.');
}

// Convert JSON data to associative array
$data = json_decode($response, true);

// Check if JSON decoding was successful
if ($data === null) {
    die('Failed to decode JSON data.');
}

// Function to check if post already exists
function post_exists($title) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type = 'post'", $title);
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
    return $post_id;
}

// Loop through each item in the JSON data
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // Check if post already exists
    if (post_exists($item['title'])) {
        echo 'Post with title "' . $item['title'] . '" already exists. Skipping...<br>';
        continue;
    }

    // Create new post
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => $item['title'], // Assuming 'title' field exists in your JSON data
        'post_content' => $item['content'], // Assuming 'content' field exists in your JSON data
        'post_status' => 'publish', // Publish the post immediately
        // You can include other fields like 'post_excerpt', 'post_category', 'tags_input', etc. as needed
    );

    // Insert the post into WordPress
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

    // Check if post was inserted successfully
    if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
        echo 'Failed to insert post: ' . $post_id->get_error_message();
    } else {
        echo 'Post inserted successfully with ID: ' . $post_id . '<br>';
    }
}
```